# Can not find python file

Tags: python, linux, file, ubuntu, terminal

I'm learning python now and I have a problem with open a python file by ubuntu terminal.In the terminal, I have current path `/home/emil` and I've copied my file mcb.py there so path to file is `/home/emil/mcb.py`.
In terminal I tried entering `./mcb.py` and `/home/emil/mcb.py` and nothing:

**No such file or directory was found**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goD98.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Ok i added screenshot. Sorry but is in Polish lang "There is no such file or directory"

Comment: can you confirm you are in the correct directory in your terminal...  What is your output from `$ pwd` and `$ ls -la`?  It is possible that your `mcb.py` is in the directory `/home/emil/` but you are in the directory `/home`

Comment: Also, opening a file is different from executing it.  `./mcb.py` will execute the file (if you have made it executable). To open the file, you need to run `vim mcb.py` or `nano mcb.py` or `emacs mcb.py`.  Of course emacs is the best option if you have it installed ;)

Comment: Finally, Do you have `python3` installed, it looks like your `mcb.py` file might reference `python3`, yet it is not installed.  To install: `$ sudo apt-get update`, and `$ sudo apt-get install python3` ...What is the exact translation of your error messages?

Comment: It seems that it's not a script file that can't be found, but python3 interpreter.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The program must have extension .pyw from tutorial. But after change I still can't see the effects. The same error. Maybe I show the code:

Answer (score 3):

Your full error message is, in English:

```
bash: /.../mcb.py: python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The first key is the `bad interpreter` part. That means that the interpreter specified in the *shebang* line (the first line, starting with `#!` is not found.

The second key is the `python3` part. Shebang interpreters must be full paths, so just `python3` is not valid.

The solution is to change the shebang line and write it correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Or if you have `python3` in a non-standard directory, to search the PATH:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

**PS #1**: When asking for help in the Internet you can run before the command: `export LANG=C`. That will disable localization and print all the error messages in English, making everybody's work easier.

**PS #2**: When copying the error message for asking help in the Internet, please, copy the full message, not only the part you think relevant. As it happens, sometimes the seemingly unimportant part is the key.